# OpenMP: are local variables automatically private?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int x; // private to each thread ?
}

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    int x; // private to each thread ?
}
```

Thank you!

P.S. If local variables are automatically private, what is the point of using *private* clause?

Comment: Yes, they're automatically private

Answer (score 60):

Yes, local variables are automatically private.

The reason for the existence of the `private` clause is so that [you don't have to change your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890539/is-there-any-difference-between-variables-in-a-private-clause-and-variables-defi/23892073#23892073).

The only way to parallelize the following code without the private clause

```
int i,j;
#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

is to change the code. For example like this:

```
int i
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

That's perfectly valid C89/C90 code but one of the goals of OpenMP is not have to change your code except to add `pragma` statements which can be enabled or disabled at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

The data within a parallel region is private to each thread.

Kindly refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Data_sharing_attribute_clauses [Data sharing attribute clauses]

Comment: I think OpenMP clauses are applied to variables declared outside the parallel region. My question is related to local variables.